# Negate(NOT) used in IFS, but I get error

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I try to use negate (NOT) in IFS, but it is not working, I get error.

```
=IFS(

NOT(TRUE); "aaa"

))
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use: 

```
=IFS(NOT(A1="abc"); "aaa")
```

to fix **#N/A**: 

```
=IFERROR(IFS(NOT(A1="abc"); "aaa"))
```

to fix blank output: 

```
=IF(A1<>""; IFERROR(IFS(NOT(A1="abc"); "aaa"); ); )
```

if there is only one negation go with: 

```
=IF(A1<>"";IFERROR(IF(NOT(A1="abc"); "aaa"); ); )
```

to simplify: 

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(A1<>""; A1<>"abc"); "aaa"; ); )
```

[image]
[image]
[image]